# Only show search suggestions in Omnibar for search mode

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I'd like to be able to use search suggestions in Chrome, but only when I'm searching -- not when I'm typing a URL.

[image: Omnibar query prefix]

Is there a way to restrict the suggestion service to turn on only when the query prefix(`?`) is typed in the Omnibar or the bar is accessed using the search shortcut (Ctrl+K)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not currently seem to be an option to do this (the whole point to the Omnibar was to consolidate and unify the address-bar and search-box). You can always [file a request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) for it (though I wouldn’t hold my breath on it getting implemented too quickly).