# How can I ban sites from Chrome's omnibar?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I've set up a couple of servers on my network, which are named simply after the service they are providing (i.e. http://[git](http://git-scm.com)/, http://[jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org)/, etc.). For simplicity, those are accessible by their short name, i.e. `http://git` instead of `http://git.my.local.domain`. Unfortunately, this interferes severely with searching from Chrome's omnibar: if I wanted to search for "git do something I want", I'd type `git`<kbd>space</kbd> and the Omnibar would instantly assume I want to search inside `http://git`, which is obviously wrong.

Is there any way I can either disable this functionality for certain sites or at least change it somehow to be activated only on <kbd>tab</kbd>, but not on <kbd>space</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a [few](https://superuser.com/questions/249993/only-show-search-suggestions-in-omnibar-for-search-mode) [related](https://superuser.com/questions/326531/removing-past-searches-from-google-chromes-omnibar) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/328515/chrome-remove-url-from-autocomplete-which-doesnt-show-up-in-history).

No, there is currently no way to control the Omnibar behavior (and the Chrome devs have repeatedly indicated that they have no desire to give such options).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Settings > Search > Manage Search Engines > Other Search Engines.
Remove entry for 'git'

Comment: This works for 'Facebook', but strangely, I don't have an entry for 'git' in there! :(