# In Chrome, can I prevent a specific google autosuggestion (NOT an auto-completion) from displaying in the omnibar dropdown?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

Let me preface this by saying there's tons of solutions out there for deleting items from your search history from showing up in the Chrome omnibar. That's NOT what I'm asking for.

When I type in the omnibar it will display matches in three categories; bookmarks (denoted with a star icon), items from your history (denoted with a page icon), and search "suggestions" (denoted with a magnifying glass icon).

I was hoping there was a way to ban certain "suggestions" from showing up.

For example, I use a tool at work that I call "lens", which I have bookmarked. When I type "lens" into the omnibar, the first result is always a "suggestion" for "lenscrafters", while my bookmark is farther down the list. I don't wear glasses and will never have a reason to select "lenscrafters" from the list. Can I prevent this (or any other suggestion) from showing up, *without* turning off suggestions entirely?

I believe this is default, universal behavior, but my current environment is:
Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) 
Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit

Comment: Have you tried right clicking suggestions? You might be able to remove individual suggestions that way

Comment: @AChildofGod Yes. I've also tried highlighting suggestions and deleteing them in a variety of ways. That simply does not seem to be a functionality that exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers I've found so far, and [this comment](https://superuser.com/a/376294/137753), this is probably not possible. It's also a very pedantic request, so I'm "closing" it with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

-type in the omnibar chrome://flags/

-find Experimental contextual omnibox suggestion set it to disable

-find New omnibox answers in suggest types set it to disable

-find Omnibox entity suggestions set it to disable

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this did not work immediately, after exiting and relaunching Chrome, or after clearing all browsing history except passwords and cookies and then exiting and relaunching.

Comment: Omnibar should by default search thru history, bookmarks and predict urls also if its not then your install might be corrupt i'd suggest uninstall and look in appdata & program files to make sure its all gone, then reinstall

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at here. Your answer seems to be a way to disable suggestions entirely. I am not trying to do that, and the problem is not that history, bookmarks, or url predictions aren't showing up in the omnibar.

Comment: give me an example so I can better help you. You dont want it showing certain history?

Comment: History is fine. The things I would like to customize are the google suggestions. As noted in the OP, these are the entries that show up with a "magnifying glass" icon next to them, as opposed to the history entries with a "page" icon, or the bookmark entries with a "star" icon. If the example I gave in the OP is not sufficient, what would be a better example? Thanks again.